#  Failure to boot after upgrade from 10.10 to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, boot, kvm-virtualization

After upgrade from 10.10 -> 11.04 -> 11.10 -> 12.04 I got this error:

[image: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-MQNjk0xPw9Q/T64lLoS4t4I/AAAAAAAAP9o/y1T4bN0p1hc/s681/IMG_20120512_165332.jpg]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Line 159.xxx `kvm_intel: unknown parameter 'nested'` says it all. You are attempting to do *nested virtualization*, i.e. run a virtual machine within another virtual machine (aka hypervisor), on a physical machine with an Intel processor. KVM supports this experimentally, but your kernel needs to have KVM with that support enabled. It looks like yours does not.
[Please see this tutorial](http://kashyapc.wordpress.com/2012/01/14/nested-virtualization-with-kvm-intel/) for details on how to enable it.

Comment: That tutorial explains how to add the 'nested' option, but that isn't the problem.  He already has the 'nested' option enable to get the error message "kvm_intel: unknown parameter 'nested'".  He actually needs to remove it because it is no longer a parameter for the kvm_intel module.

Answer (score 0):

When you upgraded it didn't remove this file `/etc/modprobe.d/qemu-system-x86.conf`. The file contains `option kvm-intel nested=1`, but the nested option is no longer available. This causes loading the module to fail.  Simply remove `/etc/modprobe.d/qemu-system-x86.conf`.